output values From Postgresql procedure
I have a working procedure in Postgresql with input and input/output vlaues. And now I'm trying to use this procedure in my code .NET Framework 4. But I can't.
If I open connection and use stored procedure:
oc.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure`
oc.CommandText = "\"My_table\".\"MY_PROCEDURE\"";

oc.ExecuteNonQuery()

I get an error because query is
SELECT * FROM CALL "My_table"."MY_PROCEDURE""`

but this query is wrong for Postgresql.
If I comment out stored procedure from my code and use this line:
oc.CommandText = "CALL "My_table\".\"MY_PROCEDURE\"(x, y, z, NULL, NULL)`

NULL for output VALUES that I want take out from procedure.
I can easily go through oc.ExecuteNonQuery()
but in this case I can't take output values because I didn't add these lines
oc.Parameters.Add("fourth_parameter", NpgsqlType.Char, 50);
oc.Parameters["fourth_parameter"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
oc.Parameters.Add("fifth_parameter", NpgsqlType.Double);
oc.Parameters["fifth_parameter"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output

How can I take output values from procedure correctly?
I try to execute query of procedure, and expect that I will be able take output values from this.

If you want to use the routine using the syntax in the first example, make it a function. You can even wrap a procedure call in a function. In the second example, that call should produce a single-row output with all inout and out parameters in separate columns: demo. Did you try to process the output of that as if it was a select that returns a single row?

Create function is a great idea. But what if i dont have access to Postgresql code? What do you mean when text SINGLE ROW? I have number of Output values value1, value2, value3 and i want to take these out for my code.

I mean a call behaves like a single-row select (as shown in the demo), returning a row with one column/field for each out or inout param of the procedure you called. My guess was the client library might be able to expose it the same way it exposes rows resulting from any other select or insert/update/delete..returning query.

No client library doesn't include this case

The InputOutput direction is made for it, the following example is showing how to use double direction parameters:
using (var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("\"My_table\".\"MY_PROCEDURE\"", conn)) {

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

     // Add input parameters
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("first_parameter", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Varchar, "x");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("second_parameter", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Varchar, "y");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("third_parameter", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Varchar, "z");

     // Add input/output parameters
    var inputOutputParam4 = new NpgsqlParameter("fourth_parameter", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Char);
    inputOutputParam4.Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;
    inputOutputParam4.Value = null;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(inputOutputParam4);

     var inputOutputParam5 = new NpgsqlParameter("fifth_parameter", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Double);
    inputOutputParam5.Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;
    inputOutputParam5.Value = null;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(inputOutputParam5);

     // Execute the stored procedure
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

     // Retrieve input/output parameters
    char resultParam4 = (char)inputOutputParam4.Value;
    double resultParam5 = (double)inputOutputParam5.Value;

     // Display the results
    Console.WriteLine("Input/Output parameter 4: " + resultParam4);
    Console.WriteLine("Input/Output parameter 5: " + resultParam5);
}


Hi, ive changed code how you advised but now i have Excepion "Parameter fourth_parameter must be set"

I a little bit fix my code, and know i dont have a previous problem with parameter, i have problem like erlier 42883: function My_table.MY_PROCEDURE(first_parameter=> character ......) dosent exist. Like i write in my question because i have procedur, not function. And this code create Query is SELECT * FROM "My_table"."MY_PROCEDURE"(first_parameter,.....). But for procefure we need CALL. How use CALL and take parameters???

Would be great to have your postgre procedure code to be sure we are looking in the right direction
